# class main no PHP inteferir $_POST

Tags: php

Cheguei numa situação que deu um resultado um pouco confuso aqui..

Tenho um arquivo .php no qual tenho uma classe chamada `main`, se eu instacio essa classe `main` -> `$main = new main` o array $_POST que antes estava com algumas variaveis fica vazio, mas se eu troco o nome da classe para `main*`, ou seja, `maind`, `mainc`, ou qualquer outro nome.. o `$_POST` não é resetado, ou se leio as variaveis antes de instanciar a classe main, mas após ela fica vazia.

O que está acontecendo quando eu instacio a classe main? será que estou sobrescrevendo alguma classe que interfira no `$_POST`?

Obs: a classe main eu mesmo criei, apelidei deste nome por não precisar ser especifico.

Comment: Não da para dizer sem o código e sem ver a chamada.

Comment: ok, daqui a pouco eu coloco, obg pelo aviso. :)

Comment: E o código :) ?